# What is causing my ATLAS tool to fail when trying to build?

Tags: python, c++, git, eigen, scons

I've been trying to install this ATLAS tool on my windows computer. The instructions are very simple and straight forward:

1. clone the ATLAS git repository: `$ git clone https://gitlab.inria.fr/alta/alta.git`
2. I should have all the mandatory dependencies installed:

-the SCons build system;

-a C++11 compiler, such as recent versions of GCC or Clang;

-Eigen >= 3.0 (libeigen3-dev package on Debian and derivatives; libeigen3 in MacPorts; eigen in Brew.)

Essentially, after I have those installed, I can run `scons` on python and it should check to see whether the required dependencies are met, and then all compilation byproducts will go to the sources/build like the instructions says. The problem is after running the `scons` command, I get the following response:

```
    scons: Reading SConscript files ...
    <<INFO>> Using config file "./configs/scons/config-windows-cl.py"
    the current platform is: win32
    Checking for C++ library dl... no
    Checking for C++ library rt... no
    Checking whether 'c++11' is supported... yes
    Checking for eigen3 using pkg-config... no
    Checking for C++ header file Eigen/Core... no
    obtaining Eigen v3.2.7
    error: downloaded file 'eigen-3.2.7.tar.gz' is inauthentic
    error: got sha256 hash ea25f177c8716e7daa618533e116706d97e25c9912e016009d8a9264e39cad57 but expected 5a50a006f83480a31f1f9beabec9e91dad95138df19363ee73ccf57676f10405
    eigen-3.2.7.tar.gz: downloaded file is inauthentic
```

The compilation process results in a `eigen-3.2.7.tar.gz` file with a `WRONG-HASH File` type. Moreover, when I open the file, it reads, *"Repository eigen/eigen not found"*.

What does it mean that the `eigen-3.2.7.tar.gz` file is inauthentic and why does it have a `WRONG-HASH File` type? My guess is that my machine is complaining that the eigen repository is not downloaded, but I thought I installed everything correctly.
Here how I went about installing the dependencies:

**Scons**

I installed Scons build system by simply typing the following command in my anaconda python environment: `conda install -c conda-forge scons`

**C++ complier**

This was actually already installed on my computer a while back ago. I can't exactly remember how it was installed, but my machine seems to recognize it on the checklist so no need to worry about that.

**Eigen**
To install this dependency I just simply cloned the repository from [here](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen) in GitHub. The Eigen folder is find inside the alta directory(the highest level directory.

I new to this, so it could be very possible that my steps to install these dependencies were not correct. Should I set some sort of environment path? I'm wondering if I installed my eigen repository correctly. To be honest, i'm not exactly sure why the build process fail, thus the issue may be something totally different then how I installed my dependencies. However, at this point I am lost and in need of further instruction or intuition.

The link to the installation page is [here](http://alta.gforge.inria.fr/install.html) . As you can see its not many instruction and they are quite simple, which makes this whole thing even more frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like there's a lot wrong here... for Windows, the results look normal: `libdl` and `librt` are linux-y things. And Windows platforms also don't have the `pkg-config` way of getting information about building with a library, so those configure results are nothing to worry about. It just sounds like the fetcher tool isn't resilient to the thing it needs to fetch already being there. You want to look at the `external` area as to why it's deciding to, and then unhappy with, fetching something that's already in place. Maybe you weren't supposed to git clone that piece in the first place? The instructions you point to hint not: "If Eigen could not be found, it is automatically downloaded from upstream."

As to your problem of not finding a `build` subdirectory, your guess is correct: scons is basically two-pass, the first pass being to read the config files and build up the dependency tree, the second being to do any required builds.  Dependency fetching must be done in the first pass in this project (there are ways to code such an animal to be a build-time thing, but that's harder so most projects don't), so once the dep checking failed, it never went on the the build phase, thus the `build` directory was never created.

Comment: So, I figured out the problem. Apparently, when I ran `scons` th first time, it create a .tar.gz file so then I ran it again, I kept complaining because the .tar.gz file was already there. There problem I am having now is the `Eigen-3.2.7.tar.gz` file has a "WRONG-HASH File type and when I open it, it says "Repository Eigen/eigen not found"... does simply cloning the repository not enough? 
Should this new issue be a separate question?

Comment: Really no need to add this same comment on two answers.. Best to update your original question with more information.  Beyond that, if alta's not responding you're going to have to figure out he sconstruct logic on your own. Checkout the docs a scons.org or come to our support channels (For help understanding SCons, but not this build system in particular)

Comment: Ok, I will go ahead and update my question!

Comment: I honestly do not know which direction to go. I spent a considerable amount of time trying to understand this. Normally error would have a file and line number that would give me some direction on where to go, but I'm lost here.

Comment: @greg see: https://scons.org/contact.html. I recommend the discord channel. We can help you get started. But doubtful anyone will have time to figure the thing out entirely.

Comment: @bdbaddog Ok and I have updated my question. Let me know if this brings new insight.

Comment: I cloned the alta project just now and tried to build and it failed completely - current scons only supports Python 3.5+ and the alta SConsctruct file has Python 2 syntax in it. You can use an older SCons but it's going to be hard to overcome the gap here in terms of getting help.  Do try with your setup to build in a completely clean alta clone - don't do the clone of eigen. Hopefully that will get you somewhere.  Otherwise you'll have to depend on the kindness of strangers. Inria are a great org but this doesn't look like an active project...

Comment: @MatsWichmann I great appreciate your help. As mentioned in the problem above, the build processes results in a eigen-3.2.7.tar.gz file that says "Repository eigen/eigen not found"" when you open it. Are you getting the same result? You also mentioned: "Do try with your setup to build in a completely clean alta clone - don't do the clone of eigen"... I tried deleting eigen and running the build and I get the same result.

Comment: @MatsWichmann You might be onto something when mentioning the version of scons that was used. That may be why my file is not authentic, although I still don't quite understand what that means. Also, where can I find older versions for scons?

Comment: Older versions are hosted on sourceforge, https://sourceforge.net/projects/scons/files/scons/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove your eigen download.
According to: http://alta.gforge.inria.fr/install.html

```
If Eigen could not be found, it is automatically downloaded from upstream. 
The downloaded file is integrity-checked, and then the software is built and 
installed under the external/build sub-directory of the source tree.
```

Comment: I did that, but I still get the error. You think by me downloading eigen tool manually, I may have disrupted the automated process? I figured since it says `"If Eigen could not be found"`, I would be ok to manually download it and it not ruin the compilation process.

Comment: You're best bet for support on this is to reach out the alta project directly. It's unlikely they check here.

Comment: So, I figured out the problem. Apparently, when I ran scons th first time, it create a .tar.gz file so then I ran it again, I kept complaining because the .tar.gz file was already there. There problem I am having now is the Eigen-3.2.7.tar.gz file has a "WRONG-HASH File type and when I open it, it says "Repository Eigen/eigen not found"... does simply cloning the repository not enough? Should this new issue be a separate question?

Comment: And I have reached out before coming here. To be honest, they haven't updated the tool since 2014, so I'm not holding my breath that they will respond.